# Unix Multiple Column Sort Issue

Tags: files, sort

I am trying to sort a file:

```
TX001;A0004|Number|5|0|Y|1        
TX001;A0110|VARCHAR|5|0|Y|4         
TX001;A1332|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|3         
TX001;B3321|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|5         
TX001;C1321|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|2      
TY001;A1234|Number|5|0|Y|3        
TY001;C2335|VARCHAR|5|0|Y|1        
TY001;B2133|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|2        
TZ001;A1234|Number|5|0|Y|3    
TZ001;A2133|VARCHAR|5|0|Y|1  
TZ001;C0133|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|2
```

The expected output result is:

```
TX001;A0004|Number|5|0|Y|1   
TX001;C1321|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|2   
TX001;A1332|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|3  
TX001;A0110|VARCHAR|5|0|Y|4  
TX001;B3321|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|5  
TY001;C2335|VARCHAR|5|0|Y|1  
TY001;B2133|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|2  
TY001;A1234|Number|5|0|Y|3  
TZ001;A2133|VARCHAR|5|0|Y|1      
TZ001;C0133|VARCHAR|15|0|Y|2  
TZ001;A1234|Number|5|0|Y|3
```

I need to sort based on the last numeric column. When I try the sort using `-n`, the order of the first column is changing.

Tried using `sort -t "|" -k 6,6n FNAM.txt` but it results numerical sort chaning the first column order.

I need to sort based on the last column numerically, keeping the first column of table name unaffected.

Comment: A more accurate description might be "sort on the first five characters of the line, and then on the last numeric field".  While the number is always a single digit as in the sample data, there's no difference between a textual sort and a numeric sort, of course.  If you added some entries starting 'TA999' to the end of the file and then wanted those entries to remain at the end of the file but still to sort by the sixth field within the group of rows sharing that prefix, then you are in for a much harder job.  In your sample data, the prefixes appear in sorted order which simplifies things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort` can sort on multiple columns with different types, but it requires the delimiter to be a single character. To handle your example and produce the expected output, you can replace the first ';' with '|', then sort on the first column alphanumerically then on the seventh (formerly sixth) numerically, and finally replace the first '|' with ';':

```
sed 's/;/|/' < FNAM.txt | sort -t\| -k1,1 -k7,7n | sed 's/|/;/'
```

The variant you tried,

```
sort -t "|" -k 6,6n FNAM.txt
```

sorts the full file only on the sixth column, numerically; `sort` isn't aware of any structure you don't tell it about, so it doesn't know it should group lines by the first few characters. So you end up with the last column completely sorted, which means mixing up the table names.

Comment: its more simple.

Comment: Thanks. this works perfect !! I never tried with changing the delimiter.

Comment: The `sed` operations are wholly unnecessary with this data, though the technique of editing field delimiters can have its uses in other data sets.  More generally, you can do things like make a stable sort by adding a line number in a pre-processing step, sorting the data according to the main criteria and then finally by the line number in ascending order, and then remove the line number in a post-processing step.

Answer (score 8):

With any [POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html#tag_20_119_13) `sort`:

```
sort -t"|" -k1,1.6 -k6n file
```

- `-t"|"` sets the delimiter to `|`.
- `-k1,1.6` sorts the first field starting from the beginning up to the 6th character <sup>[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html#tag_20_119_13)</sup>.
- `-k6n` sort then the 6th field numberic.

---

<sup>[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html#tag_20_119_13)</sup> From the manpage:

```
POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and C the character position in the field;
```

Comment: This works with any POSIX-compliant `sort`; it does not use any feature specific to GNU `sort`.